# Accessing class name in trait of the class using that particular trait

Tags: php, class, traits

I’m trying to access the class name inside my trait of the class that is using the trait. Is there a way to do this?

After much research, I’m not sure this is possible, but figured I’d check here before I tapped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible!

I was thinking about the trait and it’s relationship to the class wrong. A trait basically extends the class, so using `get_class($this)` inside the trait I get the class of the object using the trait.

Another option is `__CLASS__`